# Proof regarding the primitives of periodic functions

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Let $
f:R \to R
$ be an integrable, periodic function. Prove that any primitive of such a function can be written as a sum of a periodic function and a function of the  form $G(x)=ax$
 where $a$ is a real constant.
The text sounds rather ambiguous to me and I can't find a decent starting point for a proof..Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=P(x)+k$ where $P(x)$ is a periodic function, $k$ is constant, you have to prove that $\int f(x)dx=P_2(x)+kx$ where $P_2(x)$ must be periodic function(prove that) and $kx$ is your $G(x)=ax$.